# What is Deferred in Anko coroutines kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko, kotlin-coroutines

In Anko coroutines library by kotlin, In that, there is one feature **bg()** for easily execute your code on the background thread. In that return type is **Deferred**. Then what is **Deferred**?

**Refrence Link**

**(1)** https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/Deferred.kt

**(2)** https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Coroutines#bg

```
  fun getData(): Data { ... }
  fun showData(data: Data) { ... }

  async(UI) {
      val data: Deferred<Data> = bg {
      // Runs in background
      getData()
      }

      // This code is executed on the UI thread
      showData(data.await())
  }
```

Comment: `Deferred` is Kotlin-specific future/promise. What's the question then?

Comment: My question is what is Deferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start, if you excuse me, by quoting the first sentence from the documentation on `Deferred` class from the first link in the question:

> Deferred value is a non-blocking cancellable future.

In fact, deferred is a synonym for *future* or *promise* ([see this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)).

The `Deferred` class is part of [`kotlinx-coroutines`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/) project that provides library support for Kotlin coroutines. The recommended way to start learning more about it is by reading this [guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md).